Word for being poked by many sharp points at once
In Javanese, being poked by a needle or a finger is called nyuluk, but being poked by all five fingers, or a brush, or a fork, or (humorously) by hair in your eyes is called nyokrok.
Is there a way to distinguish these concepts in English? I ask because I vaguely feel like there should be something related.

Anglophones wouldn't normally make a distinction between being poked / pierced by a single point or several (and the tines on a dining fork are so close together you probably couldn't even feel the difference between being stabbed by a knife or by a fork). But you could refer to being pincushioned if it was imortant to convey the sense of ...by multiple sharp points.

@FumbleFingers thank you, that is an acceptable answer to me! I wasn't looking for exact answer, just a general sense

We have adjectives that make such distinctions.  prickly vs pointy, for example.
